# Swing Date picker with custom look

Tags: java, swing, datepicker

I need a free date picker (for commercial projects), with fully customizable look. I mean not only overriding colours, but also borders, shapes, button icons, etc... Does such picker exist, or it would be easier to write my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SwingX](http://java.net/projects/swingx) offers the JXDatePicker and SwingX is licenced under LGPL 2.1

In [this article](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t45447.html) they go over the usage of the JXDatePicker. There is also probably a tutorial or sample code on the SwingX website, but I am having trouble accessing their website.

Comment: Doesn't LGPL mean that end user should be able to modify my code for his own needs?

Comment: @Natalia AFAIK, no. It means that if you modify their code, you need to publish the modified code (you need to give it back to the community), but you do not need to provide your own code.

Comment: Can't figure out, how to customize it's look.

Comment: @Natalia I have never used it, but I believe that you should retrieve the "MonthView" of the datepicker. On the MonthView, it seems that there are many parameters to modify the appearance of the popup. Take a look at the source code and examples to find out more: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.jtstand/jtstand-desktop/1.0/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXDatePicker.java http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.jtstand/jtstand-desktop/1.0/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXDatePicker.java

Comment: I looked there before asked. Everything I see there about borders or background is private

Comment: @Natalia all methods look `public` to me: `org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.setBoxPaddingX(int)
org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.setBoxPaddingY(int)
org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.setDayForeground(int, Color)
org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.setFlaggedDayForeground(Color)
org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.setMonthStringBackground(Color)
org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.setMonthStringForeground(Color)
org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.setSelectionBackground(Color)
org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.setSelectionForeground(Color)
org.jdesktop.swingx.JXMonthView.setTodayBackground(Color)`

Comment: @Natalia You could also choose to implement your own `MonthUI` or extend `BasicMonthViewUI` if the parameters are not sufficients.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake, guess I got tired of varios datepickers. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You need Kai Toedter's [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/)...
It is free, very well implemented, internationalizable and in case you use Netbeans, you can add these Javabeans to your component palette and drag and drop them anywhere you need.

Comment: JCalendar has GPL license, and I can't provide any source code

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice `DateComboBox` available in the JIDE Common Layer which is published under a dual license: GPL and free commercial license. I think it may worth evaluating it after making sure the license is friendly enough.